# I want to count the number of palms delimited in this image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import *
from pylab import *
i = cv2.imread('C:/Users/fouza/OneDrive/Bureau/stage_pfe/data/test1.PNG')  


# Function to map each intensity level to output intensity level.
def pixelVal(pix, r1, s1, r2, s2):
    if (0 <= pix and pix <= r1):
        return (s1 / r1)*pix
    elif (r1 < pix and pix <= r2):
        return ((s2 - s1)/(r2 - r1)) * (pix - r1) + s1
    else:
        return ((255 - s2)/(255 - r2)) * (pix - r2) + s2
    
    
pixelVal_vec = np.vectorize(pixelVal)
r1 = 126
s1 = 0
r2 = 120
s2 = 255
img = pixelVal_vec(i, r1, s1, r2, s2)
imshow(img)
```

This is the initial image.

[image]

This is the segmentation of my main image.

[image]

As you can see I want to calculate the number of palm trees in the image. But the problem is that I have in zones several palm trees grouped together so I can not work with the area of the zones.

Comment: one of the possible solutions is that you can fill this contours, erode and dilate them

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already tried and it didn't work because the problem is to count the trees in these contours.